# Android: Use a SWITCH statement with setOnClickListener/onClick for more than 1 button?

Tags: android, button, listener

Let's say I have a few buttons in a LinearLayout, 2 of them are:

```
mycards_button = ((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button_MyCards));
exit_button = ((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button_Exit));
```

I register `setOnClickListener()` on both of them:

```
mycards_button.setOnClickListener(this);
exit_button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

How do I make a SWITCH to differentiate between the two buttons within the Onclick ?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(?????){
    case ???:
      /** Start a new Activity MyCards.java */
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyCards.class);
      this.startActivity(intent);
      break;
    case ???:
      /** AlerDialog when click on Exit */
      MyAlertDialog();
      break;
}
```

Comment: I prefer not to use Menus for this, as I can put the buttons anywhere I want on the Layout ...

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

      case R.id.Button_MyCards: /** Start a new Activity MyCards.java */
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyCards.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        break;

      case R.id.Button_Exit: /** AlerDialog when click on Exit */
        MyAlertDialog();
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that this will not work in Android library projects (due to http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields) where you will need to use something like:

```
int id = view.getId();
if (id == R.id.Button_MyCards) {
    action1();
} else if (id == R.id.Button_Exit) {
    action2();
}
```

Comment: works just great ! I wonder how I haven't tried this by myself! 
Thanks a lot dude.

H.

Comment: When I do this eclipse tells me : "case expressions must be constant expressions"

Comment: @dell116 It's telling you that because the variable that you are using in case is not a constant. Declare the variable that it complaining about as final, for example "`final int x = 5;`", or declare a variable y "`final int y = x;`" right before the switch if x must be modified before reaching the case.

Comment: You cannot use R.id.* in switch-case since they are not `final` variables.

Comment: @MasterGaurav You can use R.id.*, unless it is an Android library project: http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields. I will add a note to the answer to address this.

Comment: @Intrications, what about Custom Dialogs? (IK they are deprecated)

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to add a new OnClickListener as parameter in setOnClickListener() and overriding the onClick()-method:

```
mycards_button = ((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button_MyCards)); 
exit_button = ((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button_Exit));

// Add onClickListener to mycards_button
mycards_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Start new activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyCards.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
});

// Add onClickListener to exit_button
exit_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Display alertDialog
        MyAlertDialog();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have always found that do be really messy

Comment: I like it, but I guess it's pretty much a matter of personal preference.

Comment: No, don't use it. Because any time you use setOnclickListener(new OnclickLisener(){...}); Android create a new thread to catch action. So imagine if you have 10 buttons, you have 10 threads, that's not good.

Comment: @Cocorico Android does not create a thread for each OnClickLister.

Comment: @cyronix. Seriously ? My android teacher said us that. But, are you right, this method is not elegant ?

Answer (score 6):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnForward, btnBackword, btnPause, btnPlay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initControl();
    }

    private void initControl() {
        btnForward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
        btnBackword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBackword);
        btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnForward.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnBackword.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPause.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnForward:
                break;
            case R.id.btnBackword:
                break;
            case R.id.btnPause:
                break;
            case R.id.btnPlay:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

inside OnCreate method :-

```
{

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener)this);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener)this);
} 

@Override
public void OnClick(View v){

    switch(v.getId()){
         case R.id.button1:
             //whatever
             break;

         case R.id.button2:
             //whatever
             break;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast your activity to an `OnClickListener` if it implements the `OnClickListener` interface.

Answer (score 1):

And there's yet a third option. In your onCreate() method, find all the button views that you have and save them as class data members.  You can then cascade a group of if-else statements to find which is which.  It's kind of messy, but it's a must if you don't know the ID of the buttons (which can be complicated if you are generating buttons in java code).

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == m_myCards) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyCards.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (v == m_exit) {
        MyAlertDialog();
    }
    else if (v == m_back) {
        finish();            
    }
```

Another nice thing about this technique is that it's flexible and quick (no having to parse IDs).  The bad thing is that you need to keep the widgets in memory.

Don't know which method is better.

Comment: Is that also possible with a switch statement?

Comment: @winklerrr - Nope, switch statements in java require constants, not variables.  That's why this example uses the less elegant series of if-else statements.

Comment: And what if you declared the method like this: `onClick(final View v)`?

Comment: @winklerrr - Nice try!  The compiler still thinks that `v` is a variable and will complain like an old man.  Some languages will allow variables , but java does not.

A common work-around is to use the ID of a View.  See ayushnvijay's or Droidvilla's answers for examples.

Answer (score 1):

I make it simple, if the layout is same i just put the intent it.

My code like this:

```
public class RegistrationMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private Button btnCertificate, btnSeminarKit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_menu);

        initClick();
    }

    private void initClick() {
        btnCertificate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Certificate);
        btnCertificate.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnSeminarKit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_SeminarKit);
        btnSeminarKit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_Certificate:
                break;
            case R.id.btn_SeminarKit:
                break;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationMenuActivity.this, ScanQRCodeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my example :first  'MainActivity' implements 'View.OnClickListener' than start the code ....

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();}


public void init(){

    foryou = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_foryou);
    following = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_following);
    popular = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_popular);
    watching = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_continuewatching);
    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);

    foryou.setOnClickListener(this);
    following.setOnClickListener(this);
    popular.setOnClickListener(this);
    watching.setOnClickListener(this);
    mProgress.setOnClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_foryou:
            foryou.setPaintFlags(foryou.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

            break;
        case R.id.btn_following:
            following.setPaintFlags(following.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

            break;
        case R.id.btn_popular:
            popular.setPaintFlags(popular.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

            break;
        case R.id.btn_continuewatching:
            watching.setPaintFlags(watching.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

            break;
        case R.id.btn_5:
            // foryou.setPaintFlags(foryou.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

            break;
        default:
            foryou.setPaintFlags(foryou.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there's another good way and it doesn't wast your time

create the methode to do whatever you want for example like this in your activity

```
public void replaceSuggest(View v) {
        optionPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        replaceWith.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        searchEdit.setText(selected);

    }
```

after creating your methode go to the xml view layout and put like this (in the view you want to apply this action, example here is the TextView will perform the click :

```
 <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/anyId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/replace"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="4dp"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
// here you write the methode name after onClick
                        android:onClick="replaceSuggest"/>
```