# case expressions must be constant expressions. Getting Error on R.id.*

Tags: android, eclipse

I got stuck on a project; and unable to understand the error. Kindly help me on that. I am getting Case Expressions Must be Constant Expressions on my every R.id , I am sharing the code here.

I am getting this error on every Case R.id ; kindly suggest

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int currentBgColor = PreferencesUtils.getBgColor(this);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_home:
        if (isShowBgSelect) {
            hideBgSelector(false);
            isShowBgSelect = false;
        }
        dismissMainCling(v);
        toggle();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_bookmark:
        if (isShowBgSelect) {
            hideBgSelector(false);
            isShowBgSelect = false;
        }
        boolean isBookmarked = false;
        for (Bookmark bm : mBookmarkList) {
            if (bm.partId == mCurrentPart && bm.chapId == mCurrentChap) {
                isBookmarked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isBookmarked) {
            showUnBookmarkDialog(mCurrentPart, mCurrentChap);
        } else {
            showSaveBookmarkDialog(mCurrentPart, mCurrentChap);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btn_bm_list:
        if (isShowBgSelect) {
            hideBgSelector(false);
            isShowBgSelect = false;
        }
        // toggleSecondary();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_background:
        if (!isShowBgSelect) {
            showBgSelector();
            isShowBgSelect = true;
        } else {
            hideBgSelector(true);
            isShowBgSelect = false;
        }
        mBtnBgSelect.setEnabled(false);
        mBtnBgSelect.setSelected(true);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_fullscreen:
        if (isShowBgSelect) {
            hideBgSelector(false);
            isShowBgSelect = false;
        }
        if (isFullScreen) {
            showController();
            mFullScreenButton.setEnabled(false);
            isFullScreen = false;
        } else {
            hideController();
            isFullScreen = true;
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btn_home_slidingmenu_left:
        toggle();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_home_slidingmenu_right:
        // toggleSecondary();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_bg_white:
        if (isShowBgSelect) {
            hideBgSelector(false);
            isShowBgSelect = false;
        }
        if (currentBgColor != Constants.BG_COLOR_WHITE) {
            PreferencesUtils.saveBgColor(this, Constants.BG_COLOR_WHITE);
            loadPart(mCurrentPart, mCurrentChap);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btn_bg_khaki:
        if (isShowBgSelect) {
            hideBgSelector(false);
            isShowBgSelect = false;
        }
        if (currentBgColor != Constants.BG_COLOR_KHAKI) {
            PreferencesUtils.saveBgColor(this, Constants.BG_COLOR_KHAKI);
            loadPart(mCurrentPart, mCurrentChap);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btn_bg_sepia:
        if (isShowBgSelect) {
            hideBgSelector(false);
            isShowBgSelect = false;
        }
        if (currentBgColor != Constants.BG_COLOR_SEPIA) {
            PreferencesUtils.saveBgColor(this, Constants.BG_COLOR_SEPIA);
            loadPart(mCurrentPart, mCurrentChap);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btn_about:
        showAboutDialog();
        break;
    case R.id.tv_contact_us:
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { getResources()
                .getString(R.string.dialog_about_email) });
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                getText(R.string.contact_prefix) + " "
                        + getText(R.string.app_name));
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,
                getText(R.string.contact_chooser)));
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int currentBgColor = PreferencesUtils.getBgColor(this);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_bookmark:
        boolean isBookmarked = false;
        for (Bookmark bm : mBookmarkList) {
            if (bm.partId == mCurrentPart && bm.chapId == mCurrentChap) {
                isBookmarked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isBookmarked) {
            showUnBookmarkDialog(mCurrentPart, mCurrentChap);
        } else {
            showSaveBookmarkDialog(mCurrentPart, mCurrentChap);
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_bookmarked_chap:
        // toggleSecondary();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_bg_white:
        if (currentBgColor != Constants.BG_COLOR_WHITE) {
            PreferencesUtils.saveBgColor(this, Constants.BG_COLOR_WHITE);
            loadPart(mCurrentPart, mCurrentChap);
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_bg_khaki:
        if (currentBgColor != Constants.BG_COLOR_KHAKI) {
            PreferencesUtils.saveBgColor(this, Constants.BG_COLOR_KHAKI);
            loadPart(mCurrentPart, mCurrentChap);
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_bg_sepia:
        if (currentBgColor != Constants.BG_COLOR_SEPIA) {
            PreferencesUtils.saveBgColor(this, Constants.BG_COLOR_SEPIA);
            loadPart(mCurrentPart, mCurrentChap);
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_about:
        showAboutDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (isShowBgSelect) {
        hideBgSelector(false);
        isShowBgSelect = false;
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: Is this code in a library project?

Comment: I changed it to if else statement but not worked. Its a java file of a project using it to read a book in mobile ..

Comment: I checked ADT14 has different switch case definitions. But unable to replicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504365/2649012

Comment: Thanks Bob! It's fixed now