# How to display numbers onto a textview clicked by user?

Tags: java, android

I created a calculator but I cannot display the numbers onto the `TextView` like every iphone/android calculator.

For example, if the user clicks 5 + 5. I want 5 + 5 to display on the textview and once you hit equals it displays 10. I've tried different ways to figure this out but I keep getting errors.

```
ClearBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        output.setText("");
    }
});

Button0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       textView.setText(textView.getText() + "0");
    }
});

Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "1");
    }
});

Button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "2");
    }
});

Button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "3");
    }
});

Button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "4");
    }
});

Button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "5");
    }
});

Button6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "6");
    }
});

Button7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "7");
    }
});

Button8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "8");
    }
});

Button9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "9");
    }
});

// Operation Buttons
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(textView == null) {
            textView.setText(" ");

        } else {
            firstValue = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText() + " ");
            addition = true;
            textView.setText(null);
        }
    }
});

subBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        firstValue = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText() + " ");
        subtract = true;
        textView.setText(null);
    }
});

divideBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        firstValue = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText() + " ");
        divison = true;
        textView.setText(null);
    }
});

multiBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        firstValue = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText() + " ");
        multiplication = true;
        textView.setText(null);
    }
});

equalBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        secondValue = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText() + " ");

        if(addition == true) {
            textView.setText(firstValue + secondValue + " ");
            addition = false;
        }

        if(subtract == true) {
            textView.setText(firstValue - secondValue + " ");
            subtract = false;
        }

        if(divison == true) {
            textView.setText(firstValue / secondValue + " ");
            divison = false;
        }

        if(multiplication == true) {
            textView.setText(firstValue * secondValue + " ");
            multiplication = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: At first set `textView.getText().toString()`

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: error looks something like this when i click 5 - 5 "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "- 5". im assuming its because of the subtract sign it saying its not a double

Comment: Hi @Sean you are getting this issue because you are trying to convert invalid double value - (e.g. "-5  or  +5 .... so on").

Comment: @Sean did you solve this yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no i did not. I cannot figure it out. Every way i tired i keep getting an error because of what Prateek said about the -5 or +5. I dont understand how to display the numbers on the textview. its very confusing

Answer (score 1):

> NumberFormatException is an Exception that might be thrown when you
>   try to convert a String into a number, where that number might be an
>   int , a float , or any other Java numeric type.

You can use **[NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)** and **[Double](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html)** .

```
Double result = new Double(textView.getText().toString());
NumberFormat nm = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
textview.setText(nm.format(result)+ "3");
```

Hope this helps you .

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try and check whether it works

```
 firstValue = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText().toString().replaceAll(" ",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a reference since you created multiple onClick listeners which is highly repetitive in your code. I'd recommend taking a look at at [Android: Use a SWITCH statement with setOnClickListener/onClick for more than 1 button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504160/android-use-a-switch-statement-with-setonclicklistener-onclick-for-more-than-1) This would allow you to set a switch case for multiple buttons without making multiple onClickListeners. Good luck with your calculator!

Comment: this is not the answer... :p