# RecyclerView adapter refresh and long click conflict

Tags: android

I have a list of items and I refresh them every one second using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, and I also have set `OnLongClickListener` on each item view. The problem is, when I long click one item, before the `onLongClick(View view)` method is called, the adapter refresh and the long click is cancelled and I have to long click again. It's a little problem but sometimes annoying. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: put a boolean as false when u refresh and later set it true, and use the boolean as if to do the other operation, or do the vise vers. check the boolean from refresh, as it is done maximum number of times, and 1 sec is too much process, you should not do that.

Comment: Why are you calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() each second . There are some alternate method too for notifying the adapter for position, for range . And if its mandatory to do it in your case you need to set a toggle(boolean or integer) and check it each time when new View bind.

Comment: I have a list of download files and I need to update the progress every one second.

Comment: In this case, make the user wait for the download to finish, then call notifyDataSetChanged once, and provide a regular long-press listener.

Comment: @Niraj Sanghani How to use a boolean value? I don't know when the user performs a long click.

Comment: @KalaBalik It is not feasible in my case, those files may be very large, and the user can long click to cancel the download

Comment: The size of the downloads or the time they take to finish don't have anything to do with it. Downloads may or may not proceed in the background. In the foreground you just display a list of the available (or ongoing or whatever) downloads and possibly a progress bar of each ongoing download.

Comment: @KalaBalik But the user will not be able to cancel the download unless it is finished.

Comment: If you include a title, a progress bar AND a cancel button in your list item, the user will be able to cancel the download.

Comment: @KalaBalik yes instead of ```OnLongClickListener``` I can use ```OnClickListener```, but I have already use ```OnClickListener``` for other tasks so I have to use ```OnLongClickListener```.

Comment: In any case, what you want to do is update list items. This is different to updating the list. Only if you want to add or remove an item to or from the list you should call `notifyDataSetChanged`. In all other cases you simply update the relevant view inside the respective item - only.

Comment: Of course you can use `OnClickListener`s on every view you have. You either include the implementation of the `onClick` method in an anonymous class at the location in your code where you set the listener of each view or you have only one `onClick` method inside your class and and differeniate between different sources through reading the `View` type parameter. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504365/3356270), for example.

Comment: @KalaBalik I know what you mean, but in my design single click is to change state(e.g. pause download), long click will display a dialog and ask the user to delete or not. I may consider notify one item every time.

Comment: Okay, i see. You need different actions for different tasks. When you say that you will "consider notify[ing] one item every time", you sound as if you want to call `notifyItemChanged`. This can also get expensive since it involves new layouts. Instead consider resetting single views (like a progress bar) only.

Comment: @KalaBalik I'll try resetting single view, thanks.